# C# - Sorting TreeView by parent nodes only

Tags: c#, sorting, treeview

I have a TreeView (treeViewNew) sorted as follows

- ParentName1

  - Field1
  - Field2
  - Field3
  - Etc...
- ParentName2

  - Etc...

With around 300 parent entries. I'd like to be able to re-sort all of my Nodes by sorting *only* the parent nodes alphabetically/numerically, carrying along their children without sorting them, since the children are in specific order relative to the parent and cannot change. I'm stumped coming up with a TreeViewNodeSorter than can pull this off correctly. Any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because the objects passed to the `IComparer` are the `TreeNode` objects, you can find out if the given nodes are child or root notes by checking the `Parent` property. If they are not root nodes, then the only thing you need to do is return a value that will ensure they remain in the same order.

This comparer compares root nodes by name and non-root nodes by index. This preserves the order of non-root nodes.

```
public class Sorter : IComparer
{
    public int Compare(object x, object y)
    {
        var tx = x as TreeNode;
        var ty = y as TreeNode;

        // If this is a child node, preserve the same order by comparing the node Index, not the text
        if (tx.Parent != null && ty.Parent != null)
            return tx.Index - ty.Index;

        // This is a root node, compare by name.
        return string.Compare(tx.Text, ty.Text);
    }
}
```